# Integration of AMP page with demandware (SFCC)

Tags: amp-html, demandware

How I can integrate some AMP page with demandware (SFCC)?

Suppose I want integrate AMP page in one of the content asset /content slot where I need to include in PDP or PLP or CLP or Home page

Comment: Visit this documentation by Mobify. It has dedicated topic specific for [Mobify Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) SDK](https://docs.mobify.com/amp-sdk/latest/).

Comment: Great!!Will check the above docs and will come back if any queries.thanks